# Include sorting of accepted answer on profile

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, sorting

I have few things on my mind:

1. I viewed my profile and I wanted to sort my answers by 
   "Accepted Answer, Votes"
2. Wanted to know how many answers I've made that is marked as 
   the accepted answer.
3. Sort by Most liked Question: I'm referring to my question who 
   have the most numbers of favorites.
4. I wanted to sort the questions I created order by accepted or 
   unaccepted questions.

**1** & **2** seems useful to me but **3** & **4** I don't think are that useful. But who knows, someone in this site might find it useful one day!

My POV:
My answer is only sorted by Votes, I also want to see a list of accepted 
answers on my profile probably not just to know how many accepted answers 
I have but also to know what are the accepted answers that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all your accepted answers:

> Search: user:me isaccepted:1

For all your questions that you've accepted an answer on:

> Search: user:me hasaccepted:1

You can sort either result by `Newest` or `Votes`.

The other sort orders/filters you want don't exist.

Comment: Thanks it's good to know that :)

Comment: @LanceRoberts : I think the ability to sort or filter my unaccepted questions has enough value that it should be built into the UI instead of relying on tag searching. I have 136 questions and a 64% accept rate and I'm sure there are other dedicated SO users who, like me, just let their acceptance rate slip, and some of those users might have 500+ questions. Since a user's "Real" reputation (ie what others think of that user) is based heavily on acceptance rate, having the sort/filter option would encourage slackers likeme to go back and do the right thing, even if it's long overdue.

Comment: Not to mention that sometimes I never get an answer I want to accept and I'd like to confirm quickly (for my own sense of integrity) that the questions I haven't accepted are ones I stand behind (or want to check up on occasionally).